# AngularJS ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have this select in AngularJS:

```
<select id="objectId" name="seccionId" class="form-control" ng-model="arguments.seccion" data-ng-options="item.id as item.valor for item in arguments.objects" required></select>
```

I like to save both values in scope, but I only save one value.

Any form to save both values?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you wanting to select *multiple* items, or are you expecting the entire object to be bound when selected to your `ng-model`?

Comment: I like to select the value (is a label and name) and when I select the name I like to save the Id and the Value in scope

Comment: See my answer below, but you just need to omit the first part of your `ng-options` expression. This will bind the entire object to your `ng-model` and then you will have access to all properties on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the entire value to be bound to `ng-model` than you can simply omit the `select` portion of your [`ng-options` expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage).

In this case, it's the `item.id` part.

```
data-ng-options="item.valor for item in arguments.objects"
```

This will ensure the entire `item` is bound to your `ng-model` when selecting.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want a multiple select. Have you tried using the attribute **multiple**:

```
<select id="objectId" name="seccionId" class="form-control" ng-model="arguments.seccion" multiple="true" data-ng-options="item.id as item.valor for item in arguments.objects" required></select>
```